# Changing font color in Excel programatically

Tags: python, excel

Font Color can be changed as `self.xlSht.Cells(1, 10).Font.Color = "color"` I don't know how to give "color" in python 2.7. Thanks in advance.
`xlSht` refers to current Excel Sheet and `Cell(1, 10)` refer to row 1 and column 10.

Comment: Please, provide some code and more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Excel COM interface @ http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/cells/Lesson2.htm the colors are as follows:

```
Color Name  Constant    Value   
Black       vbBlack     &h00     
Red         vbRed       &hFF     
Green       vbGreen     &hFF00   
Yellow      vbYellow    &hFFFF   
Blue        vbBlue      &hFF0000     
Magenta     vbMagenta   &hFF00FF     
Cyan        vbCyan      &hFFFF00     
White       vbWhite     &hFFFFFF
```

Since you too seem to be using the Excel COM interface using the `win32api` Python module, I see no reason to assume it would be using color codes any different from those specified in the general Excel COM documentation.